# Hiding Parse.com URL on Reset Password Email sent from API not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, parse-platform, hosting

When I try to remove the URL of the reset password email it gives me a link like this

hiddenurl.net?link=%2Fapps%2Fapp%2Frequest_password_reset&token=buC9vYyLf1cuGfjuGhL6R3SS3&username=hidden

and when I copy and paste this link onto my web browser it takes me to the homepage of my website.

I've tried to upload the `user_management.html` file that Parse provides on there Hide Parse.com URLs subtopic of the settings page on Parse.com.

It is to broad as I uploaded the page to every section of my site. (The home directory, public_html, and all the folders)

Answer (score 3):

After you uploaded the file to the server did you provide the url of where it was located. You can place it anywhere but I opted for the public_html folder so the url for me looked like this. http://example.com/user_management.html    It should be typed in the field just like the above example with the .html and no trailing slash.

I have included an image as well. I have tested on my install and works well minus needing to adjust the file to expand the iFrame to show the button otherwise you have to scroll within the iFrame to see the button.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your advice. That worked it seems I just forgot to add the '/user_management.html'.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct install. My problem was I was forgetting the "http://" part. Thank you very much!